# Как добавлять товары в корзину на sql?

Tags: sql, база-данных, sqlite

У меня  есть четыре таблицы в БД SQLite: Пользователь, корзина ,товар и заказ. В таблице "Товар" хранится список продуктов(товаров) с id, его разделом(к примеру "овощи"), его именем и ценой. Пользователь должен сначала собрать(оформить) корзину, выбрав нужные ему товары, а потом сделать заказ. Как сделать так чтобы в одной корзине был список из этих самых товаров и их количеством?
Вот схема, которую я решил собрать перед тем как все делать
[image: схема]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно ввести понятие ЭлементКорзины (или ТоварВКорзине) или что-то в этом духе.

В таблице Продукты у вас хранится описание товаров без привязки к какому-либо покупателю вообще. А вот ЭлементКорзины должен ссылаться на конкретную корзину, конкретный Продукт и так же иметь поле количество.

Comment: Спасибо, я уже сам догадался до этогг